# Unable to set the value of input field onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created this custom dropdown which has custom radio buttons.
I get the value of the selected radio button and set it to span tag successfully.

What i am not getting is : i want to set the same value in the input field that is present in the dropdown, but the value is not getting set.

i use pure js as well as jquery to do so but the value is alerting and not setting into the input field.

code is live here: http://thekabir.in/onsitego-planlisting2017/index.html

Steps: click on check brands dropdown and select any brand..

jquery and js used are

```
//filters dropdown   
function DropDown(el) {
  this.dd = el;
  this.placeholder = this.dd.children('span');
  this.opts = this.dd.find('div.dropdown li');
  this.val = '';
  this.index = -1;
  this.initEvents();
  }
  DropDown.prototype = {
  initEvents : function() {
      var obj = this;
      obj.dd.on('click',function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        $(this).parent().toggleClass("border-active");
        $('.filters').toggleClass('border-bottom');
        $(this).children('.dropdown').css('width',$(window).width());
        var deID = $(this);

        if(deID[0].id == 'devicebrand')
        {
          $('#devicebrand i.icon-down-arrow-1').addClass('icon-up-arrow-1').removeClass('icon-down-arrow-1');
        }
        return false;
      });
      obj.opts.on('click',function(e){
          // e.preventDefault();
          $(this).parent().addClass('hidden');
          $(this).addClass('active');
          var opt = $(this);
          obj.val = opt.text();
          obj.index = opt.index();
          obj.placeholder.text(obj.val);
          var currentID = $(this).parents('div.wrapper-dropdown-3')[0].id;

          if(currentID == 'devicebrand')
          {
            $('#devicebrand.wrapper-dropdown-3 .dropdown li').removeClass('active');
            $('#devicebrand.wrapper-dropdown-3 .dropdown li span').removeClass('icon-selected-radio-yellow').addClass('icon-oval-3-copy-3');
            $('#devicebrand i.icon-up-arrow-1').addClass('icon-tick-filled').removeClass('icon-up-arrow-1');
            $('.more-brands').addClass('hidden');
            $('.covered').removeClass('hidden');
            $('#manual-brand-input').val(obj.val);
          }
          $(this).children('span').removeClass('icon-oval-3-copy-3').addClass('icon-selected-radio-yellow');
          $(this).parent().toggleClass("border-active");
          $('.dropdown input').val('');
          e.stopPropagation();
      });
  },
  getValue : function() {
      return this.val;
  },
  getIndex : function() {
      return this.index;
  }
  };
  $(function() {
  var dd = new DropDown( $('#devicebrand') );
  $(document).click(function() {
      // all dropdowns
      $('.wrapper-dropdown-3').removeClass('active');
  });
  });
```

Html :

```
<div class="filter check-brand">
    <div id="devicebrand" class="wrapper-dropdown-3" tabindex="1">
      <i class="icon icon-brand"></i>
      <span data-val="-1">check brand </span>
      <div class="dropdown brand">
        <span class="icon-cross-it"></span>
        <div class="side-info">
          <p class="SELECT-YOUR-MOBILE-P">SELECT YOUR MOBILE BRAND  </p>
          <p class="One-line-to-explain">One line to explain why he needs to select his city. Along with more information.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="city-selection">
          <ul>
            <li><span class="icon-oval-3-copy-3"></span><a href="#" data-val="htc">HTC</a></li>
            <li><span class="icon-oval-3-copy-3"></span><a href="#" data-val="motorola">motorola</a></li>
            <li><span class="icon-oval-3-copy-3"></span><a href="#" data-val="xiaomi">xiaomi</a></li>
            <li><span class="icon-oval-3-copy-3"></span><a href="#" data-val="lg">LG</a></li>
            <li><span class="icon-oval-3-copy-3"></span><a href="#" data-val="samgsung">samgsung</a></li>
            <li><span class="icon-oval-3-copy-3"></span><a href="#" data-val="sony">sony</a></li>
            <li><span class="icon-oval-3-copy-3"></span><a href="#" data-val="huawei">huawei</a></li>
            <li><span class="icon-oval-3-copy-3"></span><a href="#" data-val="google pixel">google pixel</a></li>
            <li><span class="icon-oval-3-copy-3"></span><a href="#" data-val="nokia">nokia</a></li>
            <li><span class="icon-oval-3-copy-3"></span><a href="#" data-val="le-eco">le-eco</a></li>
          </ul>
          <div class="more-brands">
            <a class="more-brands-btn" href="javascript:void(0);">+ 254 Brands</a>
          </div>
          <div class="manual-brand">
            <input placeholder="Enter your brand if not found above " id="manual-brand-input" class="manual-brand-input ui-autocomplete-input" value="" autocomplete="off" type="text"><span class="icon-shape_4"></span>
          <ul id="ui-id-1" tabindex="0" class="ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-autocomplete ui-front" style="display: none;"></ul></div>
          <div class="covered hidden">
            <p><span class="icon-tick"></span>Congratulations! Free Pick &amp; Drop service available in your city</p>
            <p><span class="icon-tick"></span>400 Service centers near you</p>
            <p><span class="icon-tick"></span>20% of people bought this near your locality</p>
            <p><span class="icon-tick"></span>3days is average repair time in your area.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="not-covered hidden">
            <p><span class="icon-not-covered-tick"></span>Sorry, we are currently present in India. We don’t cover your City.</p>
            <p>We can briefly state here why we dont cover particular city. Or if at all we are in process of including it.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <i class="icon-down-arrow-1"></i>
      <i class="icon-orange-cross hidden"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here is the fiddle for the same. 
    https://jsfiddle.net/kvab7wyd/1/

Comment: post some html codes too

Comment: @Naila just edited

Comment: can you create fiddler??

Comment: @DarshakGajjar just did

Comment: Pls find fiddler here :- https://jsfiddle.net/5qca3jf0/

Comment: @razorranjan https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/xfvazk17/ ok it works in the fiddle now to.

Comment: @DarshakGajjar i have updated the actual dropdown code plz check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main change is here: $('.dropdown input').val($(this).find('a').data('val'));

```
//filters dropdown
  function DropDown(el) {
      this.dd = el;
      this.placeholder = this.dd.children('span');
      this.opts = this.dd.find('div.dropdown li');
      this.val = '';
      this.index = -1;
      this.initEvents();
  }
  DropDown.prototype = {
      initEvents : function() {
          var obj = this;
          obj.dd.on('click',function(){
            $(this).toggleClass("active");
            $(this).parent().toggleClass("border-active");
            $('.filters').toggleClass('border-bottom');
            $(this).children('.dropdown').css('width',$(window).width());
            var deID = $(this);

            if(deID[0].id == 'devicebrand')
            {
              $('#devicebrand i.icon-down-arrow-1').addClass('icon-up-arrow-1').removeClass('icon-down-arrow-1');
            }
            return false;
          });
          obj.opts.on('click',function(e){
              // e.preventDefault();
              $(this).parent().addClass('hidden');
              $(this).addClass('active');
              var opt = $(this);
              obj.val = opt.text();
              obj.index = opt.index();
              obj.placeholder.text(obj.val);
              var currentID = $(this).parents('div.wrapper-dropdown-3')[0].id;

              if(currentID == 'devicebrand')
              {
                $('#devicebrand.wrapper-dropdown-3 .dropdown li').removeClass('active');
                $('#devicebrand.wrapper-dropdown-3 .dropdown li span').removeClass('icon-selected-radio-yellow').addClass('icon-oval-3-copy-3');
                $('#devicebrand i.icon-up-arrow-1').addClass('icon-tick-filled').removeClass('icon-up-arrow-1');
                $('.more-brands').addClass('hidden');
                $('.covered').removeClass('hidden');
              }
              $(this).children('span').removeClass('icon-oval-3-copy-3').addClass('icon-selected-radio-yellow');
              $(this).parent().toggleClass("border-active");
              console.log($(this).data('val'));
              $('.dropdown input').val($(this).find('a').data('val'));
              e.stopPropagation();
          });
      },
      getValue : function() {
          return this.val;
      },
      getIndex : function() {
          return this.index;
      }
  };
  $(function() {
      var dd = new DropDown( $('#devicebrand') );
      $(document).click(function() {
          // all dropdowns
          $('.wrapper-dropdown-3').removeClass('active');
      });
  });
```

Comment: this is working in the fiddle but when i put the same code in my live code its not getting updated...

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**

Applied my answer to OP's [<kbd>**Fiddle**</kbd>](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/xfvazk17/)

Store your value in a variable, then set the input's value equal to the variable. The way you had it was not working because `document.getElementById('input').value` is plain JavaScript expression and `$(this).attr(data-)` is jQuery expression, if you mix them, you must take dereference the jQuery by using `$(obj).get()` or dot notation `$(obj)[0]`, although I'm not entirely sure it would be worth the trouble in doing so. BTW use `e.preventDefault()` when using links that don't go anywhere, that'll stop that irritating jumping when clicking them. I also used `.data()` instead of `.attr()` it's the same result either way but `.data()` looks cleaner.

**SNIPPET**

```js
$('.dropdown li a').on('click', function(e){
    var data = $(this).data('val');
    e.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById('manual-brand-input').value = data;
  
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filter check-brand">
    <div id="devicebrand" class="wrapper-dropdown-3" tabindex="1">
      <i class="icon icon-brand"></i>
      <span data-val="-1">check brand </span>
      <div class="dropdown brand">
        <span class="icon-cross-it"></span>
        <div class="side-info">
          <p class="SELECT-YOUR-MOBILE-P">SELECT YOUR MOBILE BRAND  </p>
          <p class="One-line-to-explain">One line to explain why he needs to select his city. Along with more information.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="city-selection">
          <ul>
            <li><span class="icon-oval-3-copy-3"></span><a href="#" data-val="htc">HTC</a></li>
            <li><span class="icon-oval-3-copy-3"></span><a href="#" data-val="motorola">motorola</a></li>
            <li><span class="icon-oval-3-copy-3"></span><a href="#" data-val="xiaomi">xiaomi</a></li>
            <li><span class="icon-oval-3-copy-3"></span><a href="#" data-val="lg">LG</a></li>
            <li><span class="icon-oval-3-copy-3"></span><a href="#" data-val="samgsung">samgsung</a></li>
            <li><span class="icon-oval-3-copy-3"></span><a href="#" data-val="sony">sony</a></li>
            <li><span class="icon-oval-3-copy-3"></span><a href="#" data-val="huawei">huawei</a></li>
            <li><span class="icon-oval-3-copy-3"></span><a href="#" data-val="google pixel">google pixel</a></li>
            <li><span class="icon-oval-3-copy-3"></span><a href="#" data-val="nokia">nokia</a></li>
            <li><span class="icon-oval-3-copy-3"></span><a href="#" data-val="le-eco">le-eco</a></li>
          </ul>
          <div class="more-brands">
            <a class="more-brands-btn" href="javascript:void(0);">+ 254 Brands</a>
          </div>
          <div class="manual-brand">
            <input placeholder="Enter your brand if not found above " id="manual-brand-input" class="manual-brand-input ui-autocomplete-input" value="" autocomplete="off" type="text"><span class="icon-shape_4"></span>
          <ul id="ui-id-1" tabindex="0" class="ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-autocomplete ui-front" style="display: none;"></ul></div>
          <div class="covered hidden">
            <p><span class="icon-tick"></span>Congratulations! Free Pick &amp; Drop service available in your city</p>
            <p><span class="icon-tick"></span>400 Service centers near you</p>
            <p><span class="icon-tick"></span>20% of people bought this near your locality</p>
            <p><span class="icon-tick"></span>3days is average repair time in your area.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="not-covered hidden">
            <p><span class="icon-not-covered-tick"></span>Sorry, we are currently present in India. We don’t cover your City.</p>
            <p>We can briefly state here why we dont cover particular city. Or if at all we are in process of including it.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <i class="icon-down-arrow-1"></i>
      <i class="icon-orange-cross hidden"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: plz try on the fiddle that i just created.

Comment: @razorranjan I just added the exact code in the middle of fiddle now it works https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/xfvazk17/

Comment: @zer00ne the value needs to be place also in the input field "Enter your brand if not found above "

Comment: @razorranjan It is scroll up

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$('.dropdown li a').click(function(e){
    $("#manual-brand-input").val($(this).attr('data-val'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a small error in my code.

```
$('.dropdown input').val('');
```

this was causing the value to be empty.

Sorry guys.